# Push data to a .net application

Tags: .net, http, sockets

Is it possible to send data directly from a server to a vb.net client application without using raw TCP sockets?

Creating a multi threaded TPC socket server is much more difficult than if a use a few simple php scripts with get and post commands. I know with http the client must request data, so if I want to respond to new data quickly I'll have to poll frequently and I want to avoid this.

My requirements are basically to respond to new that arrives in the server as quickly as possible and at the same time minimize data transfer. What protocol is best suited for this or will I have to use raw TCP sockets?

I must still create the server, so I can do it in any language, but I want to keep it as simple as possible. I'm using amazon web services, so I don't think scaling or too many connection will be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Will you have many clients or  just one?
2. "Raw" TCP sockets are not that scary in .NET (see below)
3. Is latency a critical concern, if so at what threshold?
4. Is the delivery of your messages critical?

Have a look at [listen for data on TCP port C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627031/listen-for-data-on-tcp-port-c-sharp) for links on how to do what you want.

EDIT:

You could also use [WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22796/WCF-Implementation-of-the-Publisher-Subscriber-Mod) (clients register with the server for callbacks), [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) as Colin suggested or [NServiceBus](http://docs.particular.net/).

Comment: Thanks. 1. More than 1 client, but less than 1000. 3. I will like to receive the messages within 5 seconds. 4. If it missing a message it's not that crucial

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SignalR? Scott Hanselmann has an excellent post about this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard about it. I'll take a look